# Using Python Sockets in Buildozer apk

Tags: android, python, sockets

I have written a kivy script and used buildozer to compile. The script is a simple kivy layout where buttons being pressed send commands over python sockets. The script runs fine on Ubuntu which I used to develop it. Using a python app like Qpython I ran the script on a android device and again it works fine. However, when I compile an apk using buildozer the python sockets do not connect. I gave the buildozer.init file INTERNET permission and still nothing. I also tried using on a rooted device with no help. Is there something I'm missing in order to make this work?

Thanks